# How to delete image from previous stage on Docker multi-stage build

Tags: docker

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build as build-stage
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /app
COPY $source/sample-api.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY $source .
RUN dotnet publish -o /publish

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /sample-api
COPY --from=build-stage /publish .
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT dotnet sample-api.dll
```

That will create 2 images

```
REPOSITORY     TAG          IMAGE ID
sample-api     latest       
<none>         <none>
```

Is it possible to delete the first stage image `<none>` from the second stage? It is not needed anymore after the COPY on the second stage is executed `COPY --from=build-stage /publish .`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This Docker behaviour is here on purpose, it leaves this image for caching purposes - for when a build will be triggered next time.

**For now there is no option to delete it while building.**

The only option to get rid of this image is to delete it manually. One of the many possibilities:

```
$ docker image prune
```

Executed afterwards. This command removes all dangling images. Specifically, it removes all images not referenced by any local container, which includes the `<none>` image you mentioned.

[ticket ref](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34151)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know I could also prune images, thought I could only prune containers. I will use "docker image prune" instead repeatedly calling "docker rmi <image id>".

Comment: `docker system prune` will prune dangling images, stopped containers, networks not in use and all build cache. It's pretty aggressive but works quite well.